# What happens if hibernate_sequences table is accidentally reset?

Tags: hibernate, id-generation

I am using hibernate with ID annotations:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
```

For some reason the hibernate_sequences table, which is managed by hibernate, has been reset. ie. Newly inserted entities have IDs (numbers) less than older entities. Is this normal? Won't there be constraint violations when the sequence value goes up to where it was before it was reset?

If yes, how can I manually edit the hibernate_sequences table to stop this? Is it as simple as looking up the largest id for each table and setting that as the sequence_next_hi_value value?

Thanks.